# Does Samsung Knox keep a log of every app running on this device?

Tags: samsung, privacy, samsung-knox

I was reading the policy of Samsung's Knox and it states that they keep the log of your personal data and apps running on your device. This is like a spyware itself by the company.  Is this true?

Comment: If the policy already says so what are you really trying to ask then? It would be best if you link the policy.